# Adding a fixed value to an address using the linker file

Tags: c, linker, embedded, gnu

I have an embedded system that I am designing using a GNU toolchain. One of the requirements is that it needs to calculate the checksum of the executable code (ROM) at runtime, and compare it to a known value. Depending on weather the calculated value is equal to the known value it will throw an error or not. I need to place the known value in flash memory( where my executable code is stored) in a way that won't change the executable code. AKA I cannot write the value to the flash in my executable code.

I know there are tools that can modify output files to place a checksum in a known address, but for IT reasons external tools are not an option. I decided to use the SHORT() command in the linker and just edit the linker to place the known checksum in a known address at write time. It is not working, and I do not know why.

Relevent Portions of the Linker Script I have:

```
MEMORY {
m_interrupts          (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x00000400
m_flash_config        (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000400, LENGTH = 0x00000010
m_interrupts_ram      (RW)  : ORIGIN = 0x1FFF0000, LENGTH = 0x00000400
m_text                (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000410, LENGTH = 0x000FFBE0
m_data                (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x1FFF0400, LENGTH = 0x0000FC00
m_data_2              (RW)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00030000
}
SECTIONS
{
.text :
{
  . = ALIGN(4);
  *(.fill)
  *(.text)                 /* .text sections (code) */
  *(.text*)                /* .text* sections (code) */
  *(.rodata)               /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
  *(.rodata*)              /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
  *(.glue_7)               /* glue arm to thumb code */
  *(.glue_7t)              /* glue thumb to arm code */
  *(.eh_frame)
  KEEP (*(.init))
  KEEP (*(.fini))
  . = ALIGN(4);
} > m_text
.... More similar sections
....down at the bottom right before stack/heap definition
__ChecksumStart = 0xFFFE0;

.checksum  : AT(__ChecksumStart)
{
. = ALIGN (0x4);
SHORT(0xABCD)
} > m_text

__ChecksumSize = SIZEOF(.checksum);
.heap :
{
  . = ALIGN(8);
  __end__ = .;
  PROVIDE(end = .);
  __HeapBase = .;
  . += HEAP_SIZE;
  __HeapLimit = .;
} > m_data_2

.stack :
{
  . = ALIGN(8);
  . += STACK_SIZE;
} > m_data_2

__StackTop   = ORIGIN(m_data_2) + LENGTH(m_data_2);
__StackLimit = __StackTop - STACK_SIZE;
PROVIDE(__stack = __StackTop);

.ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
} //end of SECTIONS block here
```

I should be able to look at location 0xFFFE0 in my executable code and see 0xABCD. I do not. I see 0xFFFFFFFF the default value. What do I need to change to make this work? I have looked at [this tutorial](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/06/23/filling-unused-memory-with-the-gnu-linker/) to get this far

Comment: How are you looking at the executable code?

Comment: Apart from changing the image base you would also have to strip the relocation table to avoid relocation during load time.

Comment: I am running my checksum algorithm over address 0x410 to 0xFFE0

Comment: I have no idea what you just said, can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: You said " should be able to look at location 0xFFFE0 in my executable code and see 0xABCD" - *How* are you looking there? Are you opening some file with hex editor? Which file? How do you generate it?

Comment: Currently the built in memory viewer in my ide but I can try making a variable

Comment: You should look in the binary

Comment: but is possible to calculate the checksum of the final binary before running the linker (which is the responsible of creating the binaries) ???

Comment: I'm going to calculate it once at runtime assuming the result is valid. Update the linker and recompile

Comment: I presume that the image part you are calculating the checksum over is not containing the address with the checksum itself? Otherwise it will change the checksum. Anyway, did you look in the binary generated as I suggested?

Comment: Yes the checksum is the address after the code getting checksumed